# .NET - What's the best way to implement a "catch all exceptions handler"

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm wondering what the best way is to have a "if all else fails catch it".

I mean, you're handling as much exceptions as possible in your application,
but still there are bound to be bugs, so I need to have something that
catches all unhandled exceptions so I can collect information and store
them in a database or submit them to a web service.

Does the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event capture everything?
Even if the application is multithreaded?

Side note: Windows Vista exposes native API functions that allow any application
to recover itself after a crash... can't think of the name now... but I'd rather not
use it, as many of our users are still using Windows XP.

Comment: It's the "Restart Manager" feature in Windows Vista: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2006/10/vista-restart-manager.html

Comment: I wrote an extensive blog post on this: [**Gotta catch 'em all: Last-chance exception handling in .NET with WinForms**](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2013/03/gotta-catch-em-all-last-chance.html)

Comment: See also [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have just played with AppDomain's UnhandledException behavior,
(this is the last stage the unhandled exception is registered at)

Yes, after processing the event handlers your application will be terminated and the nasty "... program stopped working dialog" shown.

:)
You *still* can avoid that.

Check out:

```
class Program
{
    void Run()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");

        do
        {
            (new Thread(delegate()
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ha-ha");
            })).Start();

        } while (Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLowerInvariant() == "x");


        Console.WriteLine("last good-bye");
    }

    int r = 0;

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref r);
        Console.WriteLine("handled. {0}", r);
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating " + e.IsTerminating.ToString());

        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Dead thread";            

        while (true)
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        //Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("...");
        (new Program()).Run();
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Do handle the unhandled for Application.ThreadException (WinForms) or DispatcherUnhandledException (WPF) at the higher level.

Comment: Handling the DispatcherUnhandledException solved my problems, forgot to update the question though. Thnx for the answer

Comment: I guess it is fair to mention, that the code above leaves every failed thread lying around forever. I.e. sooner or later you will have loads of zombie threads hanging around. Personally I don't find that very useful.

Comment: I agree. That produced zombies. In sorrow I accept this alternative to killing my application immediately after the handler exits. After all, before letting the dead thread sleep forever, you can send a report to your server, let the user finish tasks at hand and exit (or restart application) gracefully.

Comment: But if that is all you want to do, you don't need to let the thread sleep forever. That is what the UnhandledException event is there for.

Comment: In case the handler exits, the runtime will show a message "XXX application has stopped working.". This is by design since .Net 2.0. Yet there is an option to make CLR work in .Net 1.1 error-handling compatibility mode (by adding a line to the manifest). Personally I do not like that design and thus I prefer my code to send error report. This is the reason of making that thread background. The unwanted message won't appear if the application kills itself (this is done intentionally after releasing resources etc).

Comment: Let the app die? Bull, that's a terrible thing to ever do to your user. And your program - use the normal channels to clean up. and What if you are writing a webserver? Can you only write toys in .net? Any serious app will need to have a watchdog to restart it anyway. Pain in the arse b/c the main program has to be always saving reload/state/where-am-i info.

Comment: Em... The app is going to die anyway. Either by your own will or with the help of CLR. Btw, a nice idea to keep a watchdog aside.

Comment: This solution is so wrong and at the same time so necessary under certain circumstances :) +1

Comment: Can I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` in _ASP.NET_ application? is ***good pattern and practice*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Almost certainly, that's a bad practice for asp.net.

Comment: This will throw if the thread's name has already been set previously: `Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Dead thread"`.

Answer (score 18):

In ASP.NET, you use the `Application_Error` function in the `Global.asax` file.

In WinForms, you use the `MyApplication_UnhandledException` in the `ApplicationEvents` file

Both of these functions are called if an unhandled exception occurs in your code. You can log the exception and present a nice message to the user from these functions.

Answer (score 13):

For Winform applications, in addition to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException I also use [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) and [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) (w/ UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException). This combination seems to catch everything.

Comment: everything except exceptions on secondary threads, timer threads, and threadpool threads!

Comment: I agree that if "handling exception" is understood as actually do something to recover from it, AppDomain's "UnhandledException" is not sufficient. However, the original question seemed to be geared only towards error reporting and not about recovering. For that purpose alone it would be sufficient.

Comment: @Steven: If the thread pool job is launched via BeginInvoke any exception from that thread is marshalled to the calling thread when EndInvoke is called.

Answer (score 7):

On the main thread, you have the following options:

- Console or Service application: [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
- WinForms application: [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)
- Web application: Global.asax's `Application_Error`

For other threads:

- Secondary threads have no unhandled-exceptions; use [SafeThread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SafeThread.aspx)
- Worker threads: (timer, threadpool) there is no safety net at all!

Bear in mind that these events do not *handle* exceptions, they merely *report* them to the application--often when it is far too late to do anything useful/sane about them

Logging exceptions is good, but monitoring applications is better ;-)

Caveat: I am the author of the [SafeThread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SafeThread.aspx) article.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe not full source code backup about CALM ?

Answer (score 4):

For WinForms, don't forget to attach to the current Thread's unhandled exception event too (especially if you are using multi threading).

Some links on best practices [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) and [here](http://dturini.blogspot.com/2005/02/exception-handling-best-practices-in.html) and [here (probably the best exception handling article for .net)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)

Comment: please link to a reference to the "current Thread's unhandled exception event", I was under the impression that there was no such thing!

Comment: ***http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx*** not found

Answer (score 2):

There's also a cool thing called [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) that will log any ASP.NET errors that occur in a web application. I know you're asking about a Winform App solution, but I felt this could be beneficial to anyone needing this type of thing on a web app. We use it where I work and it's been very helpful in debugging (especially on production servers!)

Here's some features that it has (pulled right off the page):

> - Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the full details of any one logged exception.
> - In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of death that
>     ASP.NET generated for a given
>     exception, even with customErrors mode
>     turned off.
> - An e-mail notification of each error at the time it occurs.
> - An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.
> - A number of backing storage implementations for the log, including
>     in-memory, Microsoft SQL Server and
>     several contributed by the community.

Comment: Doesn't matter that I asked about non-web apps, this is still pretty useful information for others! so +1

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor most exceptions in that handler even in multithreaded apps, but .NET (starting with 2.0) won't allow you to cancel unhandled exceptions unless you enable the 1.1 compatibility mode. When that happens the AppDomain will be shut down no matter what. The best you could do is launch the app in a different AppDomain so that you can handle this exception and create a new AppDomain to restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following approach, which works and reduces greatly the amount of code ( yet I am not sure if there is a better way or what the pitfalls of it might be.
Whenever you call: 
I quess the quys giving minuses would be polite enough to clarify their actions ; )

```
try 
{
    CallTheCodeThatMightThrowException()
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace ();
    Utils.ErrorHandler.Trap ( ref objUser, st, ex );
} //eof catch
```

And here is the ErrorHandler code : 
Just to make clear- : objUser - is the object modelling the appusers ( you might get info such as domain name , department , region etc. for logging purposes
ILog logger - is the logging object - e.g. the one performing the logging activities
StackTrace st - the StackTrace object giving you debugging info for your app

```
using System;
using log4net; //or another logging platform

namespace GenApp.Utils
{
  public class ErrorHandler
  {
    public static void Trap ( Bo.User objUser, ILog logger, System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st, Exception ex )
    {
      if (ex is NullReferenceException)
      { 
      //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof if

      if (ex is System.InvalidOperationException) 
      {
        //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof if

      if (ex is System.IndexOutOfRangeException) 
      {
        //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof if

      if (ex is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
      {
        //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof if

      if (ex is System.FormatException)
      {
        //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof if

      if (ex is Exception)
      {
        //do stuff for this ex type
      } //eof catch

    } //eof method 

  }//eof class 
} //eof namesp
```

Comment: This will only catch exceptions on the current thread. I.e. it is of little use if CallTheCodeThatMightThrowException creates or uses other threads.

Answer (score 0):

In a manged GUI app, by default, exceptions that originate in the GUI thread are handled by whatever is assigned to the Application.ThreadException.

Exceptions that originate in the other threads are handled by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.

If you want your GUI thread exceptions to work just like your-non GUI ones, so that they get handled by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, you can do this:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
```

An advantage to catching the GUI thread exceptions using ThreadException is that you can give the use the options of letting the app continue.   To make sure no config files are overriding default behavior, you can call:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

You are still vulnerable to exceptions from badly behaved native dlls.  If a native dll installs its own handler using Win32 SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, it is supposed to save the pointer to the previous filter and call it too.   If it doesn't do that, your handler wont' get called.