# How to troubleshoot .NET 2.0 Error Reporting messages in the event log?

Tags: c#, .net, crash, event-log, crash-reports

I work on an open source product called [EVEMon](http://evemon.battleclinic.com/) written in C# targeting the .NET 2.0 platform, I have one user who is suffering from a strange .NET crash that we have been unable to resolve.

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID: 5000
Date: 4/29/2009
Time: 10:58:10 PM
User: N/A
Computer: removed this
Description:
EventType clr20r3, P1 evemon.exe, P2 1.2.7.1301, P3 49ea37c8, P4
system.windows.forms, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889dee7, P7 6cd3, P8 18, P9
system.argumentexception, P10 NIL.

Data:
//hex representation of the above Description
```

The application itself crashes with out displaying an error (despite having a error handling UI), the above messages was copied out of the Windows Event log. The end user has re-installed .NET and updated to the latest versions. The .PDB files are distributed with every release version of the program to aid in debugging and testing, the user with the problem in question has the full complement of PDB files for the correct version of EVEMon.

Is there a specific, tried and tested technique to analyse and diagnose this type of crash? and if so what tools and technologies are available to aid in debugging?

### Special Thanks

I would like to give special thanks to Steffen Opel and highlight that [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814560/how-to-troubleshoot-net-2-0-error-reporting-messages-in-the-event-log/1082254#1082254) whilst not directly answering the question I was asking, addressed the bigger issue with my code base that the global error handling was missing an important component.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how I would tackle the problem for a end user with a crash.

1. Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows at http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx
2. Once the tools are installed (they end up going to C:\Program Files\ by default) start a command line window.
3. Change to the directory which contains adplus (e.g "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)").
4. Run the follwing command. This will start the application and attach adplus.

> `adplus -crash -o C:\debug\ -FullOnFirst -sc C:\path\to\your\app.exe`

### After the crash dump is created

Once the application crashes start WinDbg and load the .dmp file that is created in C:\debug. (File --> Open Crash Dump)

Execute these commands to see the stack trace and hopefully find the problem.

To load SOS for debugging

- Pre .NET 4.0

> ```
> .loadby sos mscorwks
> ```

- .NET 4.0

> ```
> .loadby sos clr
> ```

To see the stack trace

```
!clrstack
```

To see a more useful stack trace

```
!clrstack –p
```

To poke inside an object..perhaps see what caused the exception

```
!do <address>
```

e.g This is the result from a application that faulted randomly with an IO exception. WinDbg pointed out the path that was being referenced which was incorrect.

```
0:009> !do 017f2b7c    
Name: System.String    
MethodTable: 790fd8c4    
EEClass: 790fd824    
Size: 124(0x7c) bytes    
 (C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)    
String: \\server\path\not_here.txt
Fields:    
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name    
79102290  4000096        4         System.Int32  1 instance       54 m_arrayLength    
79102290  4000097        8         System.Int32  1 instance       53 m_stringLength    
790ff328  4000098        c          System.Char  1 instance       5c m_firstChar    
790fd8c4  4000099       10        System.String  0   shared   static Empty    
    >> Domain:Value  00161df8:790d884c <<    
7912dd40  400009a       14        System.Char[]  0   shared   static WhitespaceChars    
    >> Domain:Value  00161df8:014113e8 <<
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the contributions from everyone. I have accepted this answer because it very specificly answers my question, giving me the steps I need to take with the end user.

Comment: One of the best SO answers I have ever seen. Short, to the point and very useful.

Comment: +1 I can't wait to try this on a machine in the field. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Peeking into your source code (trunk) indicates that your unhandled exception handling seems to be incomplete in regard to Windows Forms applications:

You need to handle **both** non-UI thread exceptions and UI thread exceptions:

- For the former you need to implement a CLR unhandled exception handler via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, which is in place already.
- For the latter you need to implement a Windows Forms unhandled exception handler via **`Application.ThreadException`**, which seems to be missing; this could indeed yield exactly those problems you are witnessing. For an implementation example see MSDN documentation of [Application.ThreadException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx).

Please note that right now you explicitly suppress catching unhandled Windows Forms exceptions via `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException)`, you'll need to change this to `UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException` to enable routing to your handler for `Application.ThreadException`, as correctly suggested by Jehof already.

Comment: That's interesting, I need to read up on this kind of Exception Handling and see what I can do to sort this out.

Comment: +1 for looking into the source code - and this smells so far like the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

What OS (Windows XP, Windows Vista, etc.) does the user use?

If Windows Vista try to disable "Problem Reports and Solutions feature" (Control Panel-->Problem Reports and Solutions-->Change Settings-->Advanced Settings-->Turn off for my programs, problem reporting)

Or try to set

```
  Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode( UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException );
```

This will always route exceptions to the ThreadException handler.

Comment: This crops up on Windows 7, XP and Vista from several users over time. The error above is from Windows XP I belive.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: there is an unhandled exception in the application.

If you have access to the machine (through remote access, etc.), try installing Visual Studio Express and starting the application. You should see a dialog offering the chance to debug the application with a new instance of Visual Studio.

It may also be that there is something preventing Windows Forms from properly initializing. I've seen forum posts that suggest that font issues can cause this -- ensure that the users have the fonts installed that your application needs plus the usual defaults such as MS SansSerif, Arial, Tahoma, Times and suchlike.

And failing that... try sacrificing a chicken over the PC. Works a charm every time!

Comment: The application in question uses an Error Handler to produce a more useful crash report with instructions to the end user (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += etc...), this is an open source project so the end user may not want some random dev logging in to his computer - worth a shot next time it happens.

Answer (score 2):

We've had issues with Exceptions in Thread-Code. If you spawn a new Thread and forget to handle an exception in the thread method, the application just "stops" - no error message, no nothing, but only an entry in the Event Log. Not even then `UnhandledExceptionHandler` is triggered.

Maybe something like this is the cause?

Comment: It could be in a worker thread, although these messages always occur at start up.

Comment: +1 here, I've seen this before (was about to answer saying pretty much the above!) ... As a first attempt at tracking the problem down, wrap any code that's executed in a worker thread in a full try-catch that logs out any exception and see what's logged..

Answer (score 1):

...if you are able to contact that suffering user, here is an

### Idea: log pre-execution stages

Instead of making a shortcut to your `program.exe`, make a shortcut to `program.bat`, which will

```
echo "Pre-start" > stage.txt
start program.exe
```

The first line of `Program.cs` will therefore be

```
File.WriteAllLines("stage.txt", "Program execution started.");
```

In the handler of `AppDomain.UnhandledException` first line will be

```
File.WriteAllLines("stage.txt", "Unhandled exception has been caught.");
```

Also, make sure that the handler does not allocate memory or resources — pre-allocate them on programs start. Handler only trigger the writing to the log.

### Comments

It is very likely that the `stage.txt` (sent by the user) will contain "Pre-start". This happens when an exception is thrown in 3rd party .dll — even before your program has started.

In that case you will need a simple checker program, which will not reference the assemblies that you `program.exe` does, but will `Assembly.Load(...)` them.

### P.S.

`stage.txt` should be placed somewhere under %APPDATA%, not in Program Files.

I found [an interesting case on Server 2003](https://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4115-Error-EventType-clr-r.aspx) and [another nice discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20171017224731/http://geekswithblogs.net/steveclements/archive/2008/04/30/error--eventtype-clr20r3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should get a more detailed stack trace by sending the `.pdb` file for that particular release to the user (to be put next to the `.exe`) and having them reproduce the crash.

Comment: The PDB files are distributed with the application, I will check to make sure they haven't been removed.

Comment: I have checked with the user, and he does indeed have the .PDB files for all assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `AppDomain.UnhandledException` in code.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219594/net-whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-catch-all-exceptions-handler/1055954#1055954) asked. See related ones too.

Comment: We do:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);