# Creating an error message that reports a crash from anywhere inside an C# application

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have an executable that is written in C# which runs fine on one computer but crashes without providing an error on another computer.

Is there a class that I can add to my code that will dump all the information relating to the crash no matter where the error occurs within the code?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814560/how-to-troubleshoot-net-2-0-error-reporting-messages-in-the-event-log) post but I was hoping to create a "catch all" error handling class that would exist in my code.

Comment: Debug the project on that "other" pc and check where the error occurs.

Comment: You haven't stated what kind of application this is. Global exception handling in ASP.NET applications is generally different to WinForms applications, for example.

Comment: Apologies.  This is an XNA Framework 4.0 project which also contains WinForms code for loading and saving files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the AppDomain exception handler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Code sample:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

            var thr = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                throw new Exception("Custom exception from thread");
            });
            thr.Start();
            thr.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //Log information from e.ExceptionObject here
        }
    }
```

In this example a custom global exception handler is registered, and then a thread is started which throws an exception after 1 second. The global exception handler is then invoked, with the custom exception that has been thrown.

Comment: I wonder if this works with an application that hosts multiple AppDomains

Comment: @Leo no, it doesn't appear to. However if you're creating further app domains it's normally trivial to register the same unhandled exception handler for each of them.