# Alternatives to SmartAssembly for exception handling and reporting?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-4.0, smartassembly

I was happy with the SmartAssembly solution for exception handling, but I reported an issue on [Red Gate forum](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=12642) and is not being solved yet.

What alternatives exists to SA? I mean with similar features (hosting your reports, sending you e-malis, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SmartAssembly has two main features - obfuscation and error reporting.

If you are using obfuscation, there are several free and commercial alternatives. The list linked to by TrueWill shows a good selection.

For exception handling, the only similar thing that comes to mind is [Exceptioneer](http://www.exceptioneer.com). A benefit it has over SmartAssembly is that there is a free version available in addition to a paid-for version.

Comment: Sadly Exceptioneer currently only handles ASP.NET. Do you have another alternative? i found Gibraltar software as another alternative.

Comment: @Hernán: I didn't realise Exceptioneer had that limitation. Your best bet (as I assume you already have a licence for SmartAssembly) would be to pursue your support issue with RedGate - their support is usually very good.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for PreEmptive Soltutions, the makers of Dotfuscator and Runtime Intelligence.

Dotfuscator also has the ability to [report on exceptions within your application](http://preemptive.com/blog/archives/187).  In addition, with Runtime Intelligence you can inject additional code into your applications so that you can also gather data on how users are using your application and which features they use (and don't use).

Dotfuscator is also a very powerful obfuscator and can even obfuscate [XAML and BAML](http://preemptive.com/blog/archives/179) in your WPF, SilverLight and WP7 applications.

You can get a free evaluation from the [PreEmptive website](http://preemptive.com/landing/eval-request).

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) supports automatic exception handling. It has a ready to use exception reporting service which you can host on your own server. The exception reports contain a lot information including values of all local variables as well as method arguments for all methods in the stack trace, system info, etc.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP, the developers of Crypto Obfuscator.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Exceptionless](http://exceptionless.com/). They have a free plan for 1 project & 1 user.

Comment: I work on the Exceptionless Project (100% oss and community driven). I'd be more than happy to help anyone and answer any questions that anyone has.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [obfuscators](http://www.csharp411.com/net-obfuscators/) out there, but you can [roll your own exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219594/net-whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-catch-all-exceptions-handler). Note that the method can vary based on the type of application.

Your exception handler can send an email, call a web service (arguably a more reliable choice), log locally, save the stack trace, or whatever you want.

Comment: I am trying to save time using a third party component, since there are details (proxies, sending e-mails, persisting information, statistics) that need some time to be well developed.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I founded MarkedUp

You can try using MarkedUp Analytic's diagnostic logging for this - supports .NET 3.5 and later and shows up instantly on your log browser.

https://markedup.com/analytics/diagnostics