# Free alternative of SmartAssembly with error reporting and dependency integration

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I tried Smart Assembly and very satisfied with it. It's error reporting capabilities are great. Dependency integration was also very cool feature. My question is there free alternatives available that works like Smart Assembly?

I tried Eazfuscator.NET and it was great obfuscator but lacks two of my favorites from Smart Assembly. Is there any free tools available for error reporting and dependency integration for .Net framework.

Comment: I had tried a variety of these solely for the purpose of integrating dependencies (which had unmanaged code) but I could achieve that only with smart assembly. sadly its not free..

Comment: related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844345/alternatives-to-smartassembly-for-exception-handling-and-reporting

Comment: AFAIK, there are no free alternatives with all these features, but if you can consider a less costly software, take a look at [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) which has all these features. DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While reading the documents of [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) i found that it includes two features called Assembly Merging and Assembly Embedding. For the sake of error reporting i created my own library. You can find this library at [CodePlex CrashReporter.NET](http://crashreporterdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Anyone can use assembly merging or embedding by following below instructions

> **Assemblies Merging**
>
> **Introduction**
>
> Assemblies merging allows to merge several assemblies into one. This
>   may be beneficial from the deployment and security points of view.
>
> Assemblies merging technology uses ILMerge utility underneath. So in
>   order to use assemblies merging please ensure that ILMerge is
>   installed on your machine. Assemblies merging is also achievable by
>   using ILMerge utility separately but at the most cases it's much more
>   handier to use assemblies merging interface provided by
>   Eazfuscator.NET.
>
> Benefits from using assemblies merging from Eazfuscator.NET vs. direct
>   ILMerge usage
>
> Eazfuscator.NET integrates automatically into the project build
>   process with the help from Eazfuscator.NET Assistant. In case of
>   direct ILMerge usage, you have to write build event handlers for the
>   project manually  Eazfuscator.NET magically handles signing options of
>   the project. In case of direct ILMerge usage, you have to supply it
>   with signing key and options manually  Eazfuscator.NET provides
>   ILMerge with target platform information which is automatically
>   detected from input assembly. In case of direct ILMerge usage, you
>   have to supply this information manually  Eazfuscator.NET feeds
>   ILMerge with all required options, so you do not have to read ILMerge
>   manual. It speeds up integration a lot
>
> By default, assemblies merging is not used during obfuscation of the
>   assembly.
>
> **Instructions**
>
> To enable assemblies merging you should apply specially formed
>   attribute(s) to your assembly. In order to do that you can use the
>   instructions below.
>
> Instructions on enabling assemblies merging
>
> Open obfuscatable project inside the IDE  Add new source file to the
>   project and call it ObfuscationSettings.cs (for C#) or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb (for Visual Basic .NET). You may prefer to use
>   another name instead of ObfuscationSettings.cs or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb  Fill ObfuscationSettings.cs with the following
>   content (C#):
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "merge with XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> For Visual Basic .NET, fill ObfuscationSettings.vb with the following
>   content:
>
> ```
> Imports System
> Imports System.Reflection
>
> <Assembly: Obfuscation(Feature:="merge with XXXXXX.dll", Exclude:=False)>
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> Change XXXXXX.dll with the file name of the assembly you want to merge
>   with.
>
> **Tip**
>
> If you want to merge with several assemblies then just add several
>   attributes:
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "merge with Assembly1.dll", Exclude = false)]
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "merge with AnotherAssembly2.dll", Exclude = false)]
> …
> ```
>
> **Note**  Usage of assemblies merging may lead to some side effects which may make obfuscation fail. If such is the case then use the
>   principle of the least common denominator – merge just those
>   assemblies which do not cause obfuscation failure.  Assemblies
>   embedding can be used in conjunction or as an alternative to
>   assemblies merging.
>
> **Custom Parameters for ILMerge**
>
> Sometimes you may need to pass custom parameters to ILMerge utility.
>   For example, you may prefer to control class internalization yourself
>   or use some tricky ILMerge feature. In order to do that you can use
>   the instructions below.
>
> **Instructions on passing custom parameters to ILMerge**
>
> Open obfuscatable project inside the IDE  Add new source file to the
>   project and call it ObfuscationSettings.cs (for C#) or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb (for Visual Basic .NET). You may prefer to use
>   another name instead of ObfuscationSettings.cs or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb  Fill ObfuscationSettings.cs with the following
>   content (C#):
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "ilmerge custom parameters: <parameters>", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> For Visual Basic .NET, fill ObfuscationSettings.vb with the following
>   content:
>
> ```
> Imports System
> Imports System.Reflection
>
> <Assembly: Obfuscation(Feature:="ilmerge custom parameters: <parameters>", Exclude:=False)>
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> Change  with the parameters you want to pass.
>   Eazfuscator.NET passes /internalize /ndebug parameters by default when
>   no attribute defined. If you do not want to pass any parameters to
>   ILMerge then change  with none string.

Assemblies Embedding Instructions

> **Assemblies Embedding**
>
> **Introduction**
>
> Assemblies embedding allows to embed assembly's dependencies into
>   assembly itself. This may be beneficial from the deployment and
>   security points of view.
>
> Assemblies embedding is similar to merging. The main difference is
>   that the assemblies are not merged into single assembly when they are
>   embedded. They just get encrypted and packed as the assembly
>   resources. As a result, there is a single assembly at the output and
>   it contains the packed dependencies at the same file.
>
> What's the point for embedding when we have merging (or vice versa)?
>   Assemblies merging delivers the best performance for the resulting
>   assemblies. They can be NGENed, they work in all constrained
>   environments (Windows Phone, Compact Framework etc.). File mappings
>   and JIT'ted code can be cached by the operating system for such
>   assemblies, bringing the blinding fast application startups. Assembly
>   merging definitely rocks.
>
> The only downside of merging is that it's not always possible to apply
>   it without breaking the application. So this is the point where
>   assemblies embedding comes to the rescue.
>
> Embedded assemblies are easy goals to achieve and they work out of the
>   box. Downsides? Well, they are present. Embedded assemblies can not be
>   NGENed, they do not work in some constrained environments (Xbox,
>   Windows Phone and Compact Framefork). The extraction of embedded
>   assemblies during the application load is a performance penalty
>   (penalty is pretty small, so it's unlikely you are able to notice it).
>
> Assemblies embedding brings some benefits as well. The embedded
>   assemblies are encrypted, so this is a securty hardening against the
>   hackers. Embedded assemblies are compressed, bringing the size
>   reduction of the resulting assembly. And of course assemblies
>   embedding is the easiest way to achieve single-file deployment, making
>   your application to consist of a single .exe (or .dll) file.
>
> **Instructions**
>
> To enable assemblies embedding you should apply specially formed
>   attribute(s) to your assembly. In order to do that you can use the
>   instructions below.  Instructions on enabling assemblies embedding
>
> Open obfuscatable project inside the IDE  Add new source file to the
>   project and call it ObfuscationSettings.cs (for C#) or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb (for Visual Basic .NET). You may prefer to use
>   another name instead of ObfuscationSettings.cs or
>   ObfuscationSettings.vb Fill ObfuscationSettings.cs with the following
>   content (C#):
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> For Visual Basic .NET, fill ObfuscationSettings.vb with the following
>   content:
>
> ```
> Imports System
> Imports System.Reflection
>
> <Assembly: Obfuscation(Feature:="embed XXXXXX.dll", Exclude:=False)>
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> Change XXXXXX.dll with the file name of the assembly you want to
>   embed.
>
> **Important**
>
> It is recommended to obsuscate the embedded assemblies.
>   **Tip**
>
> Eazfuscator.NET automatically finds the assembly path when only the
>   file name is supplied.  If you prefer to specify the exact file path
>   to assembly then you can use script variables:
>
> ```
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = @"embed $(InputDir)\Lib\AssemblyToEmbed.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> **Tip**
>
> If you want to embed several assemblies then just add several
>   attributes:
>
> ```
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed Assembly1.dll", Exclude = false)]
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed AnotherAssembly2.dll", Exclude = false)]
> …
> ```
>
> **Tuning**
>
> Embedded assemblies are compressed and encrypted by default. You may
>   prefer to turn off the compression, encryption or them both. In order
>   to do that, please read the notes below.
>
> The full notation of a custom attribute for assembly embedding has the
>   following form:
>
> ```
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed [flags] XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> where [flags] is an optional enumeration of flags separated by spaces.
>
> The list of available flags is presented in the table below.
>
> **Below is the list of flags for assembly embedding attribute**
>
> Flag Description  no_compress Disables the compression  no_encrypt
>   Disables the encryption  no_satellites Disables automatic embedding of
>   satellite assemblies  load_from_file Instructs Eazfuscator.NET to load
>   the embedded assembly from file instead of memory during the
>   obfuscated assembly run-time. This can be used to preserve a
>   meaningful value of Location property from System.Reflection.Assembly
>   type.
>
> Let's take a look on examples.
>
> Example 4.24. Embed assembly without compression and encryption
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed [no_compress no_encrypt] XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> Example 4.25. Embed assembly without encryption; compression is
>   enabled
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed [no_encrypt] XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> Example 4.26. Embed assembly; compression and encryption are enabled
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed XXXXXX.dll", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> Example 4.27. Embed own satellite assemblies; compression and
>   encryption are enabled
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
>
> [assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed satellites", Exclude = false)]
> ```
>
> **Troubleshooting** While assembly embedding is the most non-intrusive way to link the assembly, some rare issues may occur. Possible issues
>   are described in this chapter together with corresponding solutions to
>   avoid them.  Location property of System.Reflection.Assembly class
>   Issue summary.  Location property of System.Reflection.Assembly class
>   is often used to find the paths of files near the assembly. While not
>   being a correct solution, this works for most deployment scenarios.
>
> What may go wrong?  First of all, Location property can have a
>   completely unexpected value when assembly shadow copying is used, thus
>   breaking the intended application logic. Secondly, Location property
>   has a null value when a corresponding assembly is embedded.
>
> Solution.  Use EscapedCodeBase property instead. This property always
>   has a correct value in all deployment scenarios. Please take a look at
>   the sample below.
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> class Program
> {
>     static string GetEulaPath()
>     {
>         var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
>         // string location = assembly.Location; // Please do not use this. This is a flawed approach
>         string location = new Uri(assembly.EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath; // <-- Use this instead
>         return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(location), "EULA.rtf");
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For error reporting you may try NBug. For dependency integration, you may use ILMerge,

http://www.nbusy.com/projects/nbug

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx

BTW, if you really like SmartAssembly, consider buying it.

Comment: Sure, but $1045 is a bit steep for what it does.