# Does anyone have a proven formula for global exception handing in a C# Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net

Global meaning "in one place" e.g. not multiple try...catches e.g. on each event handler. Proven meaning "known to work" - I'm aware covering both .NET and other exceptions is not straightforward.

Thanks.

**Solution** coded from answers below.

Note: this is believed to cover exceptions from additional threads.

```
static class Program
{
    static void MyHandler(Exception e)
    { MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    static void MyThreadExceptionEventHandler(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
    { MyHandler(args.Exception);
        // App continues.
    }

    static void MyAppExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    { MyHandler((Exception)args.ExceptionObject);
        // There follows a OS "needs to close" dialog, terminating app.
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        // For UI thread exceptions
        Application.ThreadException += 
            new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyThreadExceptionEventHandler);

        // Force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        // For non-UI thread exceptions
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
            new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyAppExceptionHandler);

        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219594/net-whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-catch-all-exceptions-handler

Comment: A proven formula? Yes. Don't do it. The global handlers are where your app can say goodbye to a logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and the Application.ThreadException  you should be good!

Answer (score 3):

The **default behavior** when it displays error dialog on unhandled exception and terminates **is a good formula**. If you don't like the look and feel of this dialog you can show your [own](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/why-cant-error-messages-be-fun.html) [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentdo) but the [principle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/user-friendly-exception-handling.html) is the same (good example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
    Application.ThreadException 
          += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(/* YOUR OWN HANDLER */);

    // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all 
    // Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(/* YOUR OWN HANDLER */);

    // Runs the application.
    Application.Run(new /* YOUR MAIN FORM*/);
}
```

Generally there is no magic 'solution' to exception handling - you have to [think](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) about [handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152354/which-exceptions-shouldnt-i-catch/7152374#7152374) specific exceptions before calling any method. There is nothing special about Windows Forms in this regard.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Does this cover exceptions from additional threads?

Answer (score 0):

Use Exception Handling Application Block and exception policy that may be adjusted in config file. I like it but it might be 'too heavy' for someone when considering very small projects.